# How to support Co Variance generics here

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Although I have seen the examples, but still I am confused how to make it working. I need to support some variance in generics.

```
public interface I1 { }

public class BaseClass<U> : List<U>
    where U : I1 {}

public class Class1 : I1 { }

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<Class1>
{
}

public class TestMain
{
    public void StartUsing()
    {
        /*Compiler error,              
         Cannot implicitly convert type 'DerivedClass' to 'BaseClass<I1>'*/
        BaseClass<I1> baseObj = new DerivedClass();
    }
}
```

What is the mistake here.

Comment: Variance is supported on interfaces but not on concrete classes. If it's possible to work with interfaces then you can solve the problem that way. If not, there may be a logical flaw in the design.

Comment: agreed with you. I have to change the design.

Answer (score 1):

First, `List<U>` is invariant, you cannot make `BaseClass` covariant if inheriting from `List<U>`.

Second, co-variant only supports interface, so you have to change `BaseClass` to interface instead of class.

Third, use `out` keyword to make an interface as covariant. So, in your case, you can declare:

```
public interface I1 { }

public interface IBaseClass<out U> : IEnumerable<U> where U : I1 { }

public class Class1 : I1 { }

public class DerivedClass : IBaseClass<Class1>
{
}
```

Then, it works:

```
IBaseClass<I1> baseObj = new DerivedClass();
```